# How to get output of specific time step in lstm layer using keras?

Tags: keras, lstm

I was trying to use keras to do entity relation extraction task.

My model looks like example code of keras **imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

However, it is different from the imdb classify task that relation is related to specific entity in sentence and there may be several relations in one sentence. So I want to get output of specific entity word in BiLSTM layer one time and then concatenate them.

for example, there is a sentence "In Baghdad, a cameraman died when an
American tank fired on the Palestine Hotel." there is several relations in this sentence. so if I want to get the relation between "cameraman" and "tank", I need to get output of "cameraman" and "tank" in biLSTM layer and send them into a MLP. So what should I do to get the output of "cameraman" and "tank" in biLSTM layer? I have tried output attribute of layer, but it seems infeasible.

It may sound confusing. To be brief, how to get output of specific time step in lstm layer?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The return_sequences=True parameter can get outputs of all time steps. Then you need to write a custom layer to extract the output of certain steps you need. AFAIK there is no direct way from keras to achieve that. It should not be too hard to write such a custom layer though.